# Form won't submit due to button's conflicting interests

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mailchimp

My website has a simple form that is linked with MailChimp. The problem is that the form's submit button has conflicting interests, specifically, there's javascript email-field validation code that
is requiring the button to have `type="submit"` written in the button code. But if I include `type=submit`, it prevents my form from submitting to MailChimp.

Here is the button code in 2 forms. The first is the form which allows javascript error validation to work but submission to MailChimp to NOT work (notice the type)

```
<button class='buttonmain' type="submit" >Submit Form</button>
```

The second form does not have type="submit" and so js validation won't work, but it will submit to MailChimp:

```
<button class='buttonmain'>Submit Form</button>
```

Here's the full form

```
<form id="form-signup_v1"
      name="form-signup_v1"
      method="POST"
      action="http://mysite.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post"
    >
    <!-- MailChimp Code -->
<input type="hidden" name="u" value="g02362223cdaf329adf5">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="32da65235dba0">

      <div class="errorstyle">
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui left labeled input">

            <input id="MERGE0"
                   name="MERGE0"
                   placeholder="My Email Address"
                   type="text"
                   data-validation="[EMAIL]">

            <div class="ui corner label">
                <i class="asterisk icon">*</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<button class='buttonmain' type="submit" >Submit</button>


</form>
```

and here's the script for validating the e-mail field.
Notice how it calls on "submit".

```
<script>

    $('#form-signup_v1').validate({
        submit: {
            settings: {
                inputContainer: '.field'
            },
            callback: {
                onBeforeSubmit: function (node) {

                    myBeforeSubmitFunction(':D', ':)', node);

                },
                onSubmit: function (node) {

                    console.log('#' + node.id + ' has a submit override.');

                    //node.submit();

                }
            }
        },
        debug: true
    });

    function myBeforeSubmitFunction(a, b, node) {

        console.log(a, b);

        $(node).find('input:not([type="submit"]), select, textarea').attr('readonly', 'true');
        $(node).append('<div class="ui active loader"></div>');

    }

    $('#prefill-signup_v1').on('click', function () {

        var form = $(this).closest('form');

        form.find('#signup_v1-name').val('John Doe');
        form.find('#signup_v1-username').val('RocketJoe');
        form.find('#signup_v1-password').val('test123');
        form.find('#signup_v1-password-confirm').val('test123');
        form.find('#signup_v1-email').val('test@test.test');
        form.find('#signup_v1-email-confirm').val('test@test.test');

    });

</script>
```

**How do I combine the 2 button code forms I posted at the beginning, so that the form IS validated with js and also submits to MC?**

Thanks so much!

Comment: Anybody?? This seems like such a simple fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself doing the following:

Changing the script to include:

```
 function myBeforeSubmitFunction(a, b, node) {
   document.getElementById("form-signup_v1").submit();
```